# Delete contacts only in "System Group: My Contacts" in Google Contacts

Tags: google-sheets, google-contacts-api

The code below deletes all the contacts in Goggle Contacts whose ID does not match the ID on Google Sheets. But the problem is it deletes all the mismatched contacts. However, I would like to delete contacts only from System Group: My Contacts.

Code:

```
function deleteSingleContacts() {
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  var contactIds = ContactsApp.getContacts().map(function(contact) {
    return contact.getId(); // Get current contact ids
  });
  var sh3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MacRadio's Customers"); // Please change accordingly
  var currentIds = sh3.getRange("R5:R").getValues().map(function(value) {
    return value[0];
  }).filter(function(val) {
    return val != "";
  })
  for (var i = 0; i < contactIds.length; i++) {
    if (currentIds.indexOf(contactIds[i]) == -1) {
      var contact = ContactsApp.getContactById(contactIds[i]);
      ContactsApp.deleteContact(contact);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ContactsApp.getContacts()` with [`ContactsApp.getContactsByGroup(group)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactsbygroupgroup) with `var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('My Contacts');`.

Comment: Sorry, but actually it doesn't helps a lot. With your suggestion I get all the contacts inside the group. But I need specific contacts one by one by ID inside "My Contacts" group :/ ...Any Idea maybe?

Comment: My bad.. Works like a charm